# Foreign key com 3 chaves primárias

Tags: mysql, sql, chave-estrangeira, chave-primária, chave-composta

Oi. Tenho essa tabela com 3 chaves primárias e preciso referenciar ela em outra tabela. Tem como?

Eu ia colocar apenas um id do tipo int na tabela mensalidade pra ser a única chave primária. Mas cada mensalidade deve ser única de um contrato e ter apenas um registro por mês/ano, por isso as 3 como chave primária.

No modelo mais simples, eu ligaria o id que é chave primária com a outra tabela e criaria uma chave estrangeira, assim: `id_mensalidade REFERENCES mensalidade(id)`. Certo?

Mas como eu faço isso nesse modelo?

Obrigado, se não ficar claro posso editar o post.

To usando o MySQL.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode criar uma chave primária de tipo inteiro para a tabela e além disso aplicar uma constraint unique aos três campos já existentes.

Comment: Eu não fiz isso porque achei descenessário os 4 bytes a mais para cada linha da minha tabela.

Comment: No caso dessa tabela, pelo baixo volume de dados me parece irrisório ter 4 bytes a mais ou a menos. Mais importantes seriam a clareza e a simplicidade de se trabalhar com a chave primária simples. Chaves compostas em geral não são muito encorajadas.

Answer (score 2):

Para referenciar uma chave primária composta seria assim:

```
FOREIGN KEY (ax,bx,cx) REFERENCES tabela_origem(a,b,c)
```